# Trying to add "Search by Genre" on Web Application but don't know what's wrong with the code

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

First of all I'm a total beginner in this.

So, trying to make a simple database search both by Search bar and Genre filters by using Genre table I've put on the sql database.

```
<form action="ItemListController">
    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="Genres">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr"
    value="<%= genre = "Fantasy" %>">Fantasy</button>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr"
    value="<%= genre = "Action" %>">Action</button>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr"
    value="<%= genre = "FPS" %>">FPS</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
public List<Item> findByKeyword(ServletContext context, String word, String genre) {
        List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + context.getRealPath("WEB-INF/webapp.db");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String sql = "select * from games where GameName like ? order by GameID";
            String sql2 = "select * from games where Genre like ? order by GameID";
            PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            stmt1.setString(1, "%" + word + "%");
            stmt2.setString(1, "%" + genre + "%");

            ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt2.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setItemId(rs.getInt("GameID"));
                item.setItemName(rs.getString("GameName"));
                item.setGenre(rs.getString("Genre"));
                item.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
                item.setImage(rs.getString("GameCover"));
                item.setPrice(rs.getInt("Price"));
                item.setLink(rs.getString("Link"));
                result.add(item);
            }
            conn.close();

            while (rs1.next()) {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setItemId(rs1.getInt("GameID"));
                item.setItemName(rs1.getString("GameName"));
                item.setGenre(rs1.getString("Genre"));
                item.setDescription(rs1.getString("Description"));
                item.setImage(rs1.getString("GameCover"));
                item.setPrice(rs1.getInt("Price"));
                item.setLink(rs1.getString("Link"));
                result.add(item);
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
```

```
@WebServlet("/ItemListController")
public class ItemListController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        
        String word = request.getParameter("keyword");
        String genre = request.getParameter("gnr");

        if (word == null) {
            word = "";
        }

        L
        ItemModel im = new ItemModel();
        // List<Item> items = im.findAll(getServletContext());
        List<Item> items = im.findByKeyword(getServletContext(), word, genre);

        
        request.setAttribute("items", items);
        request.setAttribute("word", word);
        request.setAttribute("genre", genre);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/itemListView3.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

the thing is, paramaters work on the URL and I can see that but doesn't do any searchs based on the filter. It returns as if it is blank and shows all the data.

Comment: I don’t see keyword in the form. This code will return anything that matches _either_ keyword or genre, so if either one is blank it will return all results.

Comment: @TimMoore 

<form action="ItemListController">
    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="Genres">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr"
    value="<%= genre = "Fantasy" %>">Fantasy</button>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr"
    value="<%= genre = "Action" %>">Action</button>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr"
    value="<%= genre = "FPS" %>">FPS</button>
    </div>
</form>

here is the gnr key. search by keyword works completely fine.

Comment: At the start of the `findByKeyword` method, add `System.out.println("word: '"+word+"'");`. Is it blank? (Updated to add missing quote)

Comment: Yes, it is. I fill it when I push it by search.

`<form action="ItemListController">
    <div class="mb-3 input-group">
     <input class="form-control text-bg-secondary" type="text"
      name="keyword" value="<%= word %>" placeholder="keyword">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      <i class="bi bi-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
     </button>
    </div>
   </form>`

Comment: OK so on each form submission _either_ the keyword or the genre will be sent to the back end, but the back end does two queries for _both_ of them and combines the results.

Comment: if `word`is null, you search with `GameName like '%%'`, so with any name not null (i.e. all items)

Comment: I want **word** to be working as blank too so it doesn’t filter queries and shows all the data when I run application at the start. When I fill the **keyword key** with data, it works as it supposed to be and shows search queries. But for the **genre** part, it doesn’t work that way for some reason. I want it to do same kinda search as search submit but not on game name but on genre as a button group.

@TimMoore so should I separate the work by different methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can assign the values directly

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr" value="Fantasy">Fantasy</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr" value="Action">Action</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="gnr" value="FPS">FPS</button>
```

further you are closing the database connection after executing the first query

```
public List<Item> findByKeyword(ServletContext context, String word, String genre) {
    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + context.getRealPath("WEB-INF/webapp.db");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        String sql;
        PreparedStatement stmt;

        if (genre != null && !genre.isEmpty()) {
            sql = "select * from games where Genre like ? order by GameID";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, "%" + genre + "%");
        } else {
            sql = "select * from games where GameName like ? order by GameID";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, "%" + word + "%");
        }

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setItemId(rs.getInt("GameID"));
            item.setItemName(rs.getString("GameName"));
            item.setGenre(rs.getString("Genre"));
            item.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
            item.setImage(rs.getString("GameCover"));
            item.setPrice(rs.getInt("Price"));
            item.setLink(rs.getString("Link"));
            result.add(item);
        }
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I see. So I should make things work in the same line by between if codes so it gonna choose either depending on the case. Thanks, helped me a lot!